# How do i dye stuff in mobile iphone/ipad? It just wont go in the slot.

Tags: terraria-mobile

I have no idea. Is it because I'm wearing pharaoh set? I'm so confused. I made it myself, can I use orange dye or pink dye on it? I have no idea! Can you help? I just paid 5 gold coins, and I'm not happy about the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Tap on the dye in your inventory to select it, then tap and hold on the dye to pick it up. drag it to the tab on the far right of the inventory screen that shows your character's head, and you should be able to drop it in the desired slot. However, if you're wearing the Pharaoh set, the chest piece covers up the legs. So if you dye your legwear you won't be able to see it.